# An "All Sites" aggregate listing of Top Users

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, top-users, users-page

On the Stack Exchange [Top Users page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) (the leagues), how about we add a line at the top for the accumulation of ALL the Stack Exchange sites, **AND** we add the same options as per the Users pages (for all of the sites, and the aggregate line); i.e. Editors and Voters (I'm not sure we need New Users there).

Answer (score 7):

This is tough, because every list you've suggested would be utterly dominated by Stack Overflow users in every way, simply based on the fact that it has a thousand times more traffic than most of our other sites.

Comment: You're right that it would probably take a Stack Overflow presence to place, but those who work a lot in other sites on top of SO would be able to shine a little.